# Even trivial serialization examples in Scala don't work. Why?

Tags: class, scala, exception, serialization

I am trying the simplest possible serialization examples of a class:

```
@serializable class Person(age:Int) {}
val fred = new Person(45)
import java.io._
val out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("test.obj"))
out.writeObject(fred)
out.close()
```

This throws exception "java.io.NotSerializableException: Main$$anon$1$Person" on me. Why?
Is there a simple serialization example?
I also tried

```
@serializable class Person(nm:String) {
    private val name:String=nm
}
val fred = new Person("Fred")
...
```

and tried to remove `@serializable` and some other permutations. The file "test.obj" is created, over 2Kb in size and has plausible contents.

## EDIT:

Reading the "test.obj" back in (from the 2nd answer below) causes

> Welcome to Scala version 2.10.3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM,
>   Java 1.7.0_51). Type in expressions to have them evaluated. Type :help
>   for more information.
>
> scala> import java.io._ import java.io._
>
> scala> val fis = new FileInputStream( "test.obj" ) fis:
>   java.io.FileInputStream = java.io.FileInputStream@716ad1b3
>
> scala> val oin = new ObjectInputStream( fis ) oin:
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream = java.io.ObjectInputStream@1f927f0a
>
> scala> val p= oin.readObject java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing
>   aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: Main$$anon$1
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1354)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
>           at .(:12)
>           at .()
>           at .(:7)
>           at .()
>           at $print()
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:734)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:983)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.loadAndRunReq$1(IMain.scala:573)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:604)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:568)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.reallyInterpret$1(ILoop.scala:756)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:801)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:713)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine$1(ILoop.scala:577)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.innerLoop$1(ILoop.scala:584)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.loop(ILoop.scala:587)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:878)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:833)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:833)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:833)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:83)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:96)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:105)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala) Caused
>   by: java.io.NotSerializableException: Main$$anon$1
>           at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1183)
>           at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
>           at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
>           at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
>           at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
>           at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
>           at Main$$anon$1.(a.scala:11)
>           at Main$.main(a.scala:1)
>           at Main.main(a.scala)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$$anonfun$run$1.apply(ScalaClassLoader.scala:71)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:139)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:71)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:139)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner$class.run(ObjectRunner.scala:28)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.run(ObjectRunner.scala:45)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner$class.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:35)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:45)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner.scala$tools$nsc$ScriptRunner$$runCompiled(ScriptRunner.scala:171)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner$$anonfun$runScript$1.apply(ScriptRunner.scala:188)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner$$anonfun$runScript$1.apply(ScriptRunner.scala:188)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner$$anonfun$withCompiledScript$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ScriptRunner.scala:157)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner$$anonfun$withCompiledScript$1.apply(ScriptRunner.scala:131)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner$$anonfun$withCompiledScript$1.apply(ScriptRunner.scala:131)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.util.package$.trackingThreads(package.scala:51)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.util.package$.waitingForThreads(package.scala:35)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner.withCompiledScript(ScriptRunner.scala:130)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner.runScript(ScriptRunner.scala:188)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner.runScriptAndCatch(ScriptRunner.scala:201)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:76)
>           ... 3 more

Comment: I can't reproduce your example. For me the serialization works on Scala 2.10.3 . Which version of Scala are you using

In general the Java Byte Code Serialization (mostly the deserialization) for Scala works. But there are some corner cases that create problems. Especially that there is no compatibility between major Scala releases bears a lot of problems. Have a look at the new scala-pickling library in Scala 2.11 : http://parleys.com/play/51c3799fe4b0d38b54f4625a/chapter0/about

Comment: I tried this example on 2.9.3, 2.10.2, 2.10.3,  and 2.11.0-RC4 (used `extends Serializable` instead of `@serializable`) and they all worked correctly using java 7

Comment: Welcome to Scala version 2.10.3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_51).

Comment: This exception appears on two different computers, Windows8 and Windows7, with the Scala and Java versions as above.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Note that `@serializable` scaladoc tells that it is deprecated since 2.9.0:

> Deprecated (Since version 2.9.0) instead of @serializable class C, use class C extends Serializable

So you just have to use `Serializable` trait:

```
class Person(val age: Int) extends Serializable
```

This works for me (type `:paste` in REPL and paste these lines):

```
import java.io.{ObjectOutputStream, ObjectInputStream}
import java.io.{FileOutputStream, FileInputStream}

class Person(val age: Int) extends Serializable {
  override def toString = s"Person($age)"
}

val os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("/tmp/example.dat"))
os.writeObject(new Person(22))
os.close()

val is = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("/tmp/example.dat"))
val obj = is.readObject()
is.close()
obj
```

This is the output:

```
// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

import java.io.{ObjectOutputStream, ObjectInputStream}
import java.io.{FileOutputStream, FileInputStream}
defined class Person
os: java.io.ObjectOutputStream = java.io.ObjectOutputStream@5126abfd
is: java.io.ObjectInputStream = java.io.ObjectInputStream@41e598aa
obj: Object = Person(22)
res8: Object = Person(22)
```

So, you can see, the [de]serialization attempt was successful.

**Edit (on why you're getting `NotSerializableException` when you run Scala script from file)**

I've put my code into a file and tried to run it via `scala test.scala` and got exactly the same error as you. Here is my speculation on why it happens.

According to the stack trace a weird class `Main$$anon$1` is not serializable. Logical question is: why it is there in the first place? We're trying to serialize `Person` after all, not something weird.

Scala script is special in that it is implicitly wrapped into an object called `Main`. This is indicated by the stack trace:

```
at Main$$anon$1.<init>(test.scala:9)
at Main$.main(test.scala:1)
at Main.main(test.scala)
```

The names here suggest that `Main.main` static method is the program entry point, and this method delegates to `Main$.main` instance method (`object`'s class is named after the object but with `$` appended). This instance method in turn tries to create an instance of a class `Main$$anon$1`. As far as I remember, anonymous classes are named that way.

Now, let's try to find exact `Person` class name (run this as Scala script):

```
class Person(val age: Int) extends Serializable {
  override def toString = s"Person($age)"
}

println(new Person(22).getClass)
```

This prints something I was expecting:

```
class Main$$anon$1$Person
```

This means that `Person` is not a top-level class; instead it is a nested class defined in the anonymous class generated by the compiler! So in fact we have something like this:

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    new {  // this is where Main$$anon$1 is generated, and the following code is its constructor body
      class Person(val age: Int) extends Serializable { ... }
      // all other definitions
    }
  }
}
```

But in Scala all nested classes are something called "nested non-static" (or "inner") classes in Java. This means that these classes always contain *an implicit reference* to an instance of their enclosing class. In this case, enclosing class is `Main$$anon$1`. Because of that when Java serializer tries to serialize `Person`, it transitively encounters an instance of `Main$$anon$1` and tries to serialize it, but since it is not `Serializable`, the process fails. BTW, serializing non-static inner classes is a notorious thing in Java world, it is known to cause problems like this one.

As for why it works in REPL, it seems that in REPL declared classes somehow do not end up as inner ones, so they don't have any implicit fields. Hence serialization works normally for them.

Comment: Amazing, this works in my Scala, too! I am still trying to figure out, what is the principal difference. override def toString?

Comment: Something must be wrong with my REPL, I get different results when running `scala test.scala` or pasting the program into REPL. BTW, the original over-2KB-objects were wrong, the correct output file is 48 bytes.

Comment: @MadaaKaama actual reason is likely that REPL wraps all your class definitions is some kind of jail with the gibberish names (thus allowing you redefine your classes, but making a work harder for serialization)

Comment: @MadaaKaama, no, the principal difference is `extends Serializable` instead of `@serializable`.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev No, `extends Serializable` also causes "java.io.NotSerializableException: Main$$anon$1" when executed from file and `@serializable` works correctly when pasted into REPL or compiled. Actually, I still cannot understand why invocation with `scala test.scala` fails.

Comment: @MadaaKaama, see my updated answer. It seems that I was able to find the reason of your error.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev Great research! Also, I upgraded my JDK to **Scala version 2.10.3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_05)** and now serialization works in all cases, supposedly with the same REPL and the same mangling, and produces a small (37 bytes) neat object file.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the Serializable Trait:

**Trivial Serialization example using Java Serialization with the Serializable Trait:**

```
case class Person(age: Int) extends Serializable
```

Usage:

*Serialization, Write Object*

```
val fos = new FileOutputStream( "person.serializedObject" )
val o = new ObjectOutputStream( fos )
o writeObject Person(31)
```

*Deserialization, Read Object*

```
val fis = new FileInputStream( "person.serializedObject" )
val oin = new ObjectInputStream( fis )
val p= oin.readObject
```

Which creates following output

```
fis: java.io.FileInputStream = java.io.FileInputStream@43a2bc95
oin: java.io.ObjectInputStream = java.io.ObjectInputStream@710afce3
p: Object = Person(31)
```

As you see the deserialization can't infer the Object Type itself, which is a clear drawback.

**Serialization with Scala-Pickling**

https://github.com/scala/pickling or part of the Standard-Distribution starting with Scala 2.11

In the exmple code the object is not written to a file and JSON is used instead of ByteCode Serialization which avoids certain problems originating in byte code incompatibilities between different Scala version.

```
import scala.pickling._
import json._

case class Person(age: Int)

val person = Person(31)
val pickledPerson = person.pickle
val unpickledPerson = pickledPerson.unpickle[Person]
```

Answer (score 1):

`class Person(age:Int) {}` is equivalent to the Java code:

```
class Person{
    Person(Int age){}
}
```

which is probably not what you want. Note that the parameter `age` is simply discarded and `Person` has no member fields.

You want either:

1. `@serializable case class Person(age:Int)`
2. `@serializable class Person(val age:Int)`

You can leave out the empty curly brackets at the end. In fact, it's encouraged.

Comment: I am aware that the `age` field disappears. My objective is to ensure that serialization works. I started with a more complex example with arrays, which did not work, and narrowed it down to an empty class, which still doesn't work!
Adding val changes nothing, still the same exception!